# Magento: Creating a drag and drop Chocolate box picker

Tags: jquery, magento, drag-and-drop

We're looking to do is replace this Flash based solution http://www.kennedyschocolates.co.uk/buy-online/make-your-own-selection this was built and integrated into Joomla / Virtuemart and has worked successfully for a number of years. However, we want to move the client over to Magento (for obvious reasons!) but the drag and drop picker is integral for our client as it provides a high percentage of orders.

This drag and drop system allows users to build their own chocolate box. Firstly they pick a box style and size, then move on to pick their chocolates - these can be filtered on type i.e milk, white, dark and flavour; nut, coffee etc. This is then added as an item to the shopping basket directly to Joomla / Virtuemart.

As we're looking at it afresh we would prefer to develop this with HTML / JavaScript rather than Flash and are interested in hearing how we can best approach this or if other people have already achieved something silmilar.

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 0):

You could use bundled product type on Magento and the rest is just implementing D&D and animating UI with prototype on template level

Comment: Yes, we think that creating a attribute set for the drag and drop products.