# Magento chocolate store

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento

We are creating a magento chocolate store,in that the problem is we want to implement a chocolate box where user can select chocloate box(4 piece,9 piece etc)and after the selection the product should be added to cart.Any Suggestions and approach.

This is similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624758/magento-creating-a-drag-and-drop-chocolate-box-picker)

But the answer there didnt serve my purpose

Thanks Karthik

Comment: What you're asking is not a technical question it's a matter of opinion. http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#default <- something interesting can be done with that I'd imagine.

Comment: What kind of page do you want this on? Product, List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use rocket science. :)

No, seriously. You will programm a lot.
You will need a drag and drop library like jQuery UI gives you.
Integrate it into your template for magento and then respond to user actions per AJAX call to magento.

So there is a lot of technology involved. JavaScript, a JavaScript library, AJAX, magento, ...

Or maybe there are magento plugins that solve your issue.